# How can I use an Arduino to simulate button presses on this Remote Control PCB

Tags: arduino, pcb

I read with interest here this post: [How can I use an Arduino to simulate button presses on this PCB](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/431183/how-can-i-use-an-arduino-to-simulate-button-presses-on-this-pcb)

I am a beginner in this and I am trying to learn how to do this based on a small remote control I would like to simulate a *fake* press using an arduino.

I am also not sure if I need to use a MOSFET as it is a very small device requiring little amperage so I think a small transistor will do ?

Basically, I would like Arduino to send a signal to the 2 red points here that will simulate a *fake* button press.

[image]

Hope I am making sense here. I appreciate any guidance or pointers on what I need to make this happen. Thanks !

More details to share:
With COM on Battery-Negative and the other lead:

- on the right side of the button = 12V. When button is pressed = 12V
- on the left side of the button = 0V. When the button is pressed = 12V.

I will just focus on one button. Disregard the other button.

@Dave Tweed
https://electronics.stackexchange.com/users/11683/dave-tweed
If you are listening, I would really appreciate if you can share some advice.

Thanks all

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I use an Arduino to simulate button presses on this PCB](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/431183/how-can-i-use-an-arduino-to-simulate-button-presses-on-this-pcb)

Comment: Welcome to SE.EE! Please don't post duplicates. Regarding your question: a small mosfet will work as good as a small BJT.

Comment: Thanks. That referenced article provided a rough guidance but I am looking for how-tos - ie.

- What to buy
- How to wire up to an arduino ?
- How to connect to those 2 points
- etc

Sorry, I am really new to this so a prescriptive guidance and how-to documentation will really help me. Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

This is just the first step towards your goal. You need to figure out  whether the buttons, when pressed, connect the chip input to battery negative (pulling the input low) or battery positive (pulling the input high).

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fKFIWL.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. Low-side switching and high-side switching.*

- Switch your multimeter to DC volts and connect the COM lead to battery negative.
- Connect the V lead to one side of SW1 and note whether you get a low (0 V) or high (+12 V).
- Now press SW1 and see if the voltage changes. If not then move to the other side of the switch and repeat.
- Repeat the test on the other switch.

If you have the arrangement of Figure 1a the solution may be fairly easy.

Comment: Thanks for your help and reply. Here are the results I got from what you asked me to do:

With COM on Battery-Negative and the other lead:
- on the right side of the button = 12V. When button is pressed = 12V
- on the left side of the button = 0V. When the button is pressed = 12V.

I will just focus on one button. Disregard the other button. What is next ?

Comment: I may not be able to help you complete this project but did you figure out whether you've got a Figure 1a or 1b circuit?

Comment: Sorry, I dont :( I am new to this.

Comment: I've added voltmeters to the schematic. Can you see it now?

Comment: Thanks. I am not sure I follow. I followed your instructions and gathered the results. See my main post for more details of the results. I had the COM to the Battery Negative and the other lead of both sides of the button. The right side reads 12V and the left reads 0. But when the button is pressed - both sides read 12V

Comment: I'm trying to get you to work out which setup you've got rather than me just tell you. Given your results have you got 1a or 1b?

Comment: Oh dear. I really dont know. I dont even know what R1 or R2 means :( Sorry

Comment: In my very amateur opinion, i thought Dave's schematic in the referenced post https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/431183/how-can-i-use-an-arduino-to-simulate-button-presses-on-this-pcb makes sense. To create a closed ground loop ?

But i have no idea how to execute on it.

Comment: That won't work in your case because your circuit is type 1b. You're missing fundamental electronics knowledge so you're really just asking someone to design a solution for you and that's not the purpose of this site. I'll just point out that you have a problem connecting a 5 V controller to your 12 V remote. You could drive a 5 V relay module from your microcontroller (Arduino) and use the relay contacts to bridge out the remote controller button.

Comment: Thanks. I have been studying what you said and trying to understand. Thanks for your guidance. Is what I have described a common setup with RF Remote Control ? Also, for the Arduino setup, is what I need just a 5V relay (10A) ? VCC to Input, GND to GND and + to 5V and the NO wires connected to the 2 outlined contacts of the RC button ?

Comment: Hi @Transistor, now that I have read up more - isnt your 1B diagram a Pull-Down resistor ? I am not sure why you labeled it as "switches pull high" 

What am I missing ?

Comment: @Softwaremaker: In many electronics systems we need to prevent the inputs from floating to an undefined state. We need to ensure that they're either close to zero volts for a logic '0' or close to the positive voltage for a logic '1'. In figure 1b the resistors pull the input low if the switch is open (not pressed) so they are "pull down". The switches, when pressed, will pull each line to logic '1' and that's what I mean when I say that the switches pull high. The switch has very low resistance so it will always win in a fight with a pull-down resistor.

Answer (score 0):

Ok. Solved.

5V relay 10A ? VCC to Input, GND to GND and + to 5V and the NO wires connected to the 2 outlined contacts of the RC button. Thanks to @Transistor for the guidance and help.

Comment: If the question is solved you should upvote and accept one or other answer.